# how to use supplement nutrition?

Tags: bodybuilding, nutrition, protein, supplements, creatine

I have started the gym 40 days ago , and ever since I managed to jump from 69 KG to 78 KG as I used true mass protein and amino X but now I have few fat around my belly which is I never had before.
this time I ordered :
- gold standard protein
- gold standard Casein
- 2222 amino
- Russian bear creatine Xtreme

I am 184 cm tall and 78 kg , I am trying to gain volume .

what is the best way to start using these supplements ?
usually I wake up around 8:30 and I get my breakfast at 9:30 . train during the evening most of the time unless its my day off . I hope this will help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Purely nutritional questions tend to get closed, but just to outline the idea;

Take 2 caps of amino with breakfast.

Take one scoop (~5 grams) of creatine with ~250ml of water 15 minutes before workout. Chug it immediately, and don't let it dissolve. It should look disgusting.

Take one protein shake sometime after workout but before bedtime. Just before bedtime has been shown to have somewhat better effect ([source](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22330017)), but it might make you sleep uneasy as you're digesting while sleeping.

If you're already using Gold's (whey), then I see no reason to use a casein product simultaneously. But since you've already bought it, you could consider having a shake a couple hours before the workout. Casein is a more slow-acting protein, and takes slightly longer to digest as it releases amino acids into the bloodstream at a slower pace.